# Positions of my fixes

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

- My prefix lost its original position
- My suffix is in a different position
- My infix is in a fatal position
- My whole switched position

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> EXCHANGED

My prefix lost its original position

> EX

My suffix is in a different position

> CHANGED

My infix is in a fatal position

> HANG

My whole switched position

> EXCHANGED